# Can one possibly use the associative property of kernels in order to work out a so-called "triple" convolution?

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

I am technically starting calculus next year but I've already started reading into it. So after finishing the Laplace transform section of Differential Equations on Khan Academy, I asked myself:

Considering the fact that the convolution transform is only defined for f(t) and g(τ), could one possibly work out say, f∗g∗h by finding the convolution (f∗g) and then evaluating *its* convolution together with, say, h(τ)?

I am asking this because I wanted to make a video on a so-called "triple" convolution, i.e. the convolution of 3 functions altogether. I am sorry if this statement seems obviously right / obviously wrong to you all, but please just remember that I am only just beginning to wrap my head around this stuff.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The convolution is indeed associative, so $(f*g)*h=f*(g*h)$. To see this I would recommend to rewrite both sides in terms of the definition of the convolution, the answer then isn't far :)

Comment: Thank you! But then, would this legitimately act as a "triple-function" convolution used to extend the idea of double-function convolution? Like the convolution of f(t), g(τ) and h(ת) or something

Comment: Well yeah I'd guess, as there is only one way to interpret $f*g*h$ as this notation is "well defined" due to associativity. A physical interpretation of the standard convolution $f*g$ is the (weighted) mean of $f$ weigthed with $g$. So $f*g*h$ is the mean of $f*g$ weighted with $h$. Or: The mean of the mean of $f$ weighted with $g$ weighted with $h$ :P Due to cummutativity you can switch the terms in the interpretation around (as $f*g=g*f$) i. e. $f*g$ is the weighted mean of $g$ weighted with $f$. Same for the triple convolution.